# d3 - labelling the calendar example

Tags: javascript, d3.js, calendar, label

I'm using d3 to build a visualisation which includes a modified version of the calendar example:
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/calendar.html.

[image]

I have turned my calendar by 90 degrees by changing the monthpath function:

```
function monthPath(t0) {
  var t1 = new Date(t0.getFullYear(), t0.getMonth() + 1, 0),
      d0 = +day(t0), w0 = +week(t0),
      d1 = +day(t1), w1 = +week(t1);
  return "M" + (d0) * z + "," + (w0 + 1) * z
      + "V" + w0 * z 
      + "H" + 7 * z
      + "V" + w1 * z 
      + "H" + (d1 + 1) * z
      + "V" + (w1 + 1) * z 
      + "H" + 0
      + "V" + (w0 + 1) * z 
      + "Z";
}
```

I would like to label the months, to the side of the calendar, at the start of each monthpath line. So I started by defining the month variable:

```
month = d3.time.format("%b"),
```

I am probably wrong but I am assuming I can insert my month variable into my monthpath function to print my labels? I'm trying to end up with a calendar similar to the one by Nathan Yau:
http://flowingdata.com/2012/01/11/vehicles-involved-in-fatal-crashes/

[image]

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: In my opinion, it would feel more natural to process the labels separately. Once you plotted the calendar, you could select each element, corresponding to 1st day of the month, get its y coordinate, and use it for corresponding label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick - insert after the `svg.selectAll("path.month")` block from the original example.

```
    var month_name = d3.time.format("%B")

svg.selectAll("text.month")
    .data(function(d) { return d3.time.months(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "month")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return week(d) * cellSize; })
    .attr("y", 8 * cellSize)
    .text(month_name);
```

You will also need to modify the margins to make room for the labels:

```
var margin = {top: 19, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 19},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left, // width
    height = 156 - margin.top - margin.bottom, // height
    cellSize = 17; // cell size
```

Comment: Hi Tarek!! this looks exciting...would you also know how we can display the actual value inside the rectangle